# Adjust touch parameters

Tags: touchscreen, multi-touch

I have some problems with my touch in my lenovo phone. For example, when I touch in two places that the distance between them is less than 2 inches, the phone thinks that it's only one touch. To fix this and more problem with the touch, I need to know how to change some parametrs of the touch. So… Do you know where those params is stored or how to change them?

My phone (lenovo s8+) is rooted, and I have terminal emulator on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware related *problem*. The touchscreen sends your system a touch event for every finger you touch it with. If the touchscreen's touch resolution is not that high, it will merge two touches to one.

You can't change the touch resolution of your touchscreen but it is possible to send custom touch events to the Android framework using some commands (I don't know them now but I used them and it is working. It is also similar to Windows' event system.)